# Is it possible to group this array?

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have an array and I need to sort this array in a multilevel array. I'm trying to group it by its fields but I can make it work. Here is the example of the array I have and what I want

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => sports
            [title] => this is sports
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => cricket
            [title] => this is cricket
            [under] => sports
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => batsman
            [title] => this is batsman
            [under] => cricket
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => sachin
            [title] => this is sachin
            [under] => batsman
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => football
            [title] => this is football
            [under] => sports
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => ronaldo
            [title] => this is ronaldo
            [under] => football
        )

)
```

I need to group this array and make it like this

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [id] => Array(
            [sports] => Array(
                [cricket] => Array(
                    [batsman] => sachin
                )
                [football] => fun
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I tried something like this but it is not working

```
foreach($my_array as $item) {
    //group them by under
    $my_grouped_array[$item['under']][] = $item;
}
```

Any suggestion will be great.

Comment: Does the data in your array come from a database? In that case, it may be simpler to change the query.

Comment: I'm getting this data from a HTML content using preg_match_all() and it is not possible to change :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the most straight-forward way of doing this:

```
function getChildren($entry,$by_parent){
    $children = array();
    if (isset($by_parent[$entry['id']])){
        foreach ($by_parent[$entry['id']] as $child){
            $id = $child['id'];
            $children[$id] = getChildren($child,$by_parent);
        }
    }
    return $children;
}

$by_parent = array();
$roots = array();
foreach ($array as $entry){
    if (isset($entry['under'])){
        $by_parent[$entry['under']][] = $entry;
    } else {
        $roots[] = $entry;
    }
}
$result = array();
foreach ($roots as $entry){
    $id = $entry['id'];
    $result[$id] = getChildren($entry,$by_parent);
}
$results = array(array('id'=>$results));
```

NOTE: This isn't *quite* the format specified in the question, but the question doesn't define how to deal with multiple leaf nodes with the same parent, and this should be easier to traverse anyway, because it's more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a recursive function that does what you want, but bare in mind that if you have more than one last element of a branch only the first one will be saved.

Here's the function:

```
function rearrange(&$result, $my_array, $element = NULL)
{
        $found = 0;
        $childs = 0;
        foreach($my_array as $one) if(@$one['under'] == $element)
        {
                $found++;
                if( ! is_array($result)) $result = array();
                $result[$one['id']] = $one['id'];

                $childs += rearrange($result[$one['id']], $my_array, $one['id']);
        }
        if( ! $childs AND is_array($result))
                $result = reset($result);

        return $found;
}
```

You can call it like that:

```
$result = array(array('id' => array()));
rearrange($result[0]['id'], $my_array);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use php object:

```
    function populateArray($my_array) {
    //Populate the array
    while ($my_array as $item) {
            $array[$item->id]['id'] = $obj->id;
            $array[$item->id]['name'] = $obj->name;
        }  
     return $array;
     }

$a = populateArray($array);    
echo $a[0]['id'].'<br />';
echo $a[0]['name'].'<br />';
```

or use new foreach

Comment: This doesn't look like it would work for at least two reasons ($obj undefined and referring to $item as an object), and even if it did, it wouldn't give the hierarchical structure that the questions asks for.

Comment: $my_array is also an array, not an object, and even if an array could be treated as an object, it still wouldn't have those properties. Plus 'as' is syntax for foreach and won't work in a while loop. And even if you fix all those issues it still doesn't answer the question.